# Inheriting the version of an optional dependency

Tags: java, maven

My company has 3 Maven projects organized as follows:

Project A depends on Project B.

Project B depends on Project C. (Project B has set Project C as an Optional dependency in their POM)

I am the owner of Project A. I would like to add Project C as a direct dependency in my POM. However, I do not want to be responsible for keeping the version of Project C up to date. Is there a way I can inherit the version of Project C specified in Project B's POM at all times?

Comment: "Inherit" is probably the wrong word because your project is not a child of either project. Is what you're trying to achieve by adding the direct dependency to make C no longer optional? It's not clear from your question. As for "*at all times*", this will not be possible since B could remove the dependency on C altogether, and then what version would you use?

Comment: Correct, I would like to make Project C non-optional for Project A as we have a few direct calls to it from Project A. Our concern is that if something is changed in Project C (or one of its dependencies) to break functionality in both Projects A and B, we only want to have to update the version in Project B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't control project B, it's not possible, except possibly with some plugin hackery.

If you *do* control project B then you can declare a dependency management section in that project which you can additionally [import into project A](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#importing-dependencies).

**Project B POM**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-c</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-c</artifactId>
        <!-- no need for version here, comes from dependencyManagement -->
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Project A POM**

```
<properties>
    <!-- using a property isn't necessary, but ensures the
         POM import and dependency stay in sync -->
    <project.b.version>2.3.4</project.b.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-b</artifactId>
            <version>${project.b.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-b</artifactId>
        <version>${project.b.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-c</artifactId>
        <!-- version is not necessary, imported from project-b's dependency management -->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This will mean Project A will default to Project B for *all* dependencies in B's dependency management section. I don't think there's a way to restrict it to just a specific one. I doubt you'll care but just something to be aware of.

Any versions that Project A defines, either in its own dependency management or directly in `<dependencies>`, will override any version brought in from Project B's dependency management.